# Parsing files with python

Tags: python

My input file is going to be something like this

```
key "value"
key "value"
... the above lines repeat
```

What I do is read the file contents, populate an object with the data and return it. There are only a set number of keys that can be present in the file. Since I am a beginner in python, I feel that my code to read the file is not that good

My code is something like this

```
ObjInstance = CustomClass()
fields = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

    for field in fields:
        for line in f:
            if line.find(field) >= 0:
                if pgn_field == 'key1':
                    objInstance.DataOne = get_value_using_re(line)
                elif pgn_field == 'key2':
                    objInstance.DataTwo = get_value_using_re(line)

return objInstance;
```

The function "get_value_using_re" is very simple, it looks for a string in between the double quotes and returns it.

I fear that I will have multiple if elif statements and I don't know if this is the right way or not.

Am I doing the right thing here?

Comment: The right thing is to use existing file format if possible such as INI (read by ConfigParser) or JSON (read by json).

Comment: My file is not going to be a config file, but a file that a user will upload.

Comment: List of string key/value pairs can be represented using INI, JSON, YAML formats whether you call it config file or not. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I am not reinventing the wheel and I should have been more clear earlier. My example of key, value is a simple example, the file will also contain a string of text which will not have a "key". The main part of my question was the if-elif and I didn't know about setattr. Thanks for letting me know about the ConfigParser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A normal approach in Python would be something like:

```
for line in f:
    mo = re.match(r'^(\S+)\s+"(.*?)"\s*$',line)
    if not mo: continue
    key, value = mo.groups()
    setattr(objInstance, key, value)
```

If the `key` is not the right attribute name, in the last line line in lieu of `key` you might use something like `translate.get(key, 'other')` for some appropriate dict `translate`.

Comment: why is this the normal approach ? to my mind, parsing s not a set of regexp.

Comment: @dzen, for _sufficiently simple_ parsing tasks REs are the cat's pajamas: fast, compact, convenient.  `pyparsing` and other tools are fine when more power is needed (e.g. to match nested parentheses), but would be overkill here, thus, not the normal approach; extensive string operations (`find` calls, slicing, etc) are often slower and more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking at the YAML parser for python. It can conveniently read a file very similar to that and input it into a python dictionary. With the YAML parser:

```
import yaml
map = yaml.load(file(filename))
```

Then you can access it like a normal dictionary with map[key] returning value. The yaml files would look like this:

```
key1: 'value'
key2: 'value'
```

This does require that all the keys be unique.

Comment: I don't think that the YAML parser will work for me, since the file can contain a some text which does not have a key.